# Source control xCode 6 and existing files

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I have a project in xCode 6 using Swift (my very first experience developing iOS Apps).

I was having problems with gestures (they are alive even after removing them from storyboard) and decide to delete the ViewController I was having problem. The program compiled as it still exists. Then I decide to delete and remove reference to file main.storyboard and everything works just as before.

I believe that is related to source control

Where are those view controllers and even the storyboard stored?

Comment: Just as a FYI, using a beta language on a beta IDE for a beta OS is _probably_ not the best place to start learning something

Comment: I agree. But I always wanted to develop for iOS and Objective-C is very different from all others languages I know. Delphi has a solution to produce Apps for iOS, but it works only in Windows (and you still need a Mac to simulate). For all those reasons, I keep trying ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the storyboard, sometimes you are creating some link between your elements and/or some part of your code.

These links will still be, even after deleting the element unless you delete the link itself.

In order to perform good deletion, you should first `right click` on the element you want to delete and suppress all its links. Then you can safely delete your element:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I believe this happened and I will take care it not happens again. What to do when these links survive to deleted component? Where are they in code? Is there any way to delete them manually after?

Comment: Well basically, if you set (for example) a `viewController` A as the delegate of a `ScrollView` B, by deleting the component B you will generate the same kind of error. The fact is this link still exist since there is still a component handling it (in this case the viewController A), in most of case I would recommend to check your `navigator panel` and see the link of the suspected component.